# onPictureTaken method - getting data as a tiff?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

So I was reading many tutorials on how to get an image preview and then save it.
The usual tutorial involves using `SurfaceHolder` and `SurfaceView` with a `PictureCallback`.

As it appears on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html#onPictureTaken%28byte%5B%5D,%20android.hardware.Camera%29) this is the signature for

`public abstract void onPictureTaken (byte[] data, Camera camera)`

Usually to save the image you can do something like

```
/** Handles data for jpeg picture */
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            // write to local sandbox file system
            // outStream =
            // CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg",
            // System.currentTimeMillis()), 0);
            // Or write to sdcard
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                    "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
            outStream.write(data);
            outStream.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
    }
};
```

but I'm not interested in saving a jpeg. I want to save a tiff image. Reading the documentation I've found a really general comment on `data` format:

> Called when image data is available after a picture is taken. The
>   format of the data depends on the context of the callback and
>   Camera.Parameters settings.

So I clicked on [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) but I didn't find anything useful.

Is there a way to save the bytes as tiff? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Look into this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureFormats()

I don't think tiff is supported by default but you can always call that method to see what is available. You can find a list of available image formats here.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html

Comment: Tiff is probably not supported by any camera hardware since nobody uses tiff anymore and the other formats are usually much better. Maybe you can find a library that can encode tiff files, http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html mentions that that should exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, TIFF is not supported directly. The most-compatible option to save a TIFF file is to decode the JPEG you receive from takePicture, by using [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29), and then use a TIFF library to save the bitmap to disk as a TIFF file.

Android's APIs do not support TIFF directly, so you'll have to find a 3rd-party library.

You might want to consider using PNG instead, since that's supported by the APIs directly; you could just call [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) then.

Comment: I need tiff unfortunately. Do you happen to know a 3rd-party library Android compatible?